# Rails 3 - Render JS after rendering JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, json, rendering

How do I execute a jquery js after rendering a json page?

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render :partial => "tables" }
    format.js
end
```

The tables.json.erb gets rendered but the js.erb file does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in js.erb won't be executed, it's for js response.

You should write the code in the ajax success callback function.

For example:

```
$.getJSON('your_request_uri', function(data){
  // write your code here.
});
```